# Given that $\log_a(b)=1.26$, where $a, b>0, a≠1$, find the value of $\log_a(\sqrt[3] b)$, to the nearest hundredth

Tags: logarithms

I'm not sure how to solve this, could someone please provide steps to solve this question? Thanks!

If $\log_a(b)=1.26$, where $a$, $b>0$, $a≠1$, then what is the value of $\log_a(\sqrt[3] b)$, to the nearest hundredth?

Comment: Do you mean $\sqrt[3] b$?  If so, then perhaps it helps if you write that as $b^{1/3}$.

Comment: Yes, thank you!

Comment: Remember the useful property for positive numbers $a,b,c$ that $\log_a(b^c)=c\log_a(b)$

Answer (score 1):

if $$log_a(b)=1.26$$
then $$log_a(b^{1/3})=log_a(b)/3=1.26/3=0.42$$